# Calling getContext() in ContentProvider#onCreate()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-context

The documentation for `ContentProvider#getContext()` states:

> Only available once `onCreate()` has been called -- this will return null in the constructor.

This elegantly avoids the question whether calling `getContext()` inside `onCreate()` will work. Will I be able to use it in order to get a context in `onCreate()`? If not, how can I get the application context inside `ContentProvider#onCreate()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `getContext()` in `onCreate()`. The framework first inits the context and then calls to `onCreate()`, as seen in the [source](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentProvider.java#1895).

"Constructor" means the Java constructor, not `onCreate()` which is a lifecycle method.

Comment: Thanks! I’m aware that `onCreate()` is just a plain method, not the constructor. It wasn’t quite clear whether `ContentProvider` sets the context before issuing the call to `onCreate()` or just after it returns. The code, however, answers that question.